# Nose - Nosetests runs on first attempt but fails on all further tries

Tags: utf-8, terminal, pip, nose

I've installed Nose using pip, when I run nosetests it executes perfectly fine. But when i try it a second time I'm presented with an error:

`SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\x90'`

I've then proceed to remove nose and reinstall again with pip. But i keep encountering the same problem. It will work on the first test `nosetests` but any subsequent tries I'm greeted with the aforementioned error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed recurring issue by updating Microsoft Framework.